# How to login with Ctrl Alt Del when Alt and AltGr are remapped to some other key?

Tags: windows, keyboard

I have remapped Alt and AltGr to another key. Only to realize that I need to press Ctrl Alt Del to log on.

I am locked in the logon screen. Am I totally screwed up? What can I do?

Comment: The three fingered salute is supposed to work independent of keyboard map  or software. How did you remap it?

Comment: Using SharpKeys

Comment: Well, that is interesting.  The reason why you shouldn't be able to remap them is so they cannot be bound to something that looks a lot like a login box but is really a password harvester.  If you can now, then I guess that is no longer a security feature.

Comment: Load the HIVE on another machine without the registry hack, reverse the hack, then within the WinRE load the hive back into your system.  You can also attempt to use a restoration point if one was created before you modified the registry.  You can also turn your physical machine into a virtual machine, load the virtual machine on another computer, but use the virtual machine software to send the keyboard combination.  At that point you can reverse your change then convert it back to a physical machine.

Comment: @Ramhound Can you explain how to do all these in an answer? I don't know how to do them.

Comment: I should point out.  The reason this was even possible was because your not using a US-based keyboard.  The website specifically indicates there is no guarantee it will work.  By using this hack with a non-US keyboard you have basically broken Windows.  The key combination isn't disabled you have just prevented Windows from interpreting one of the keys and thus it cannot trigger the functionality.

Comment: @Utku - No;  I will not post an answer that explains how to do any of those things.  I don't have the time nor resources to write an answer that would meet my expectations of an answer.  "Protect you from yourself - if you disable your DEL key and can’t login because CtrlAltDel doesn’t work now, you’ll have to reformat" - Sometimes the best help one can provide is teaching the hard lesson.

Answer (score 0):

Insert a second keyboard and use that. Keyboard mappings in Windows are device specific to my knowledge. For example, you could have US and UK QWERTY keyboard plus a Korean Dvorak keyboard all plugged into the same machine.

Comment: Do you have a source for that?

Comment: I've been trying to find one and the short answer is no. I have laptops bought in different countries however, and a full size desktop keyboard bought in a third country. All 3 keyboards have different layouts, but both laptops (win 7 / win 10) switch to the layout for the desktop keyboard when I plug it in, then switch back to the layout for their internal keyboard when I disconnect it.

Comment: Interesting, I'll do some independant research myself. Unfortunately all my keyboards are UK ones.